# Select Case with Function EndsWith()

Tags: vb.net, select-case

The code below works, I can't help thinking there is a better way to do this though. Is anyone experienced with using functions in conjunction with Select Statements.
The code I would expect to work would be something along the lines...

```
Select Case File.EndsWith()
Case "example 1", Case "example2"
```

This code works:

```
Select Case File.EndsWith(File)
    Case tFile.EndsWith("FileA.doc")
        sbExisting.AppendLine(Report.sbStart.ToString)
        sbExisting.AppendLine(Report.sbHeaders.ToString)
        sbExisting.AppendLine(Report.sbItems.ToString)
        sbExisting.AppendLine(Report.sbSubreport.ToString)
        sbExisting.AppendLine(Report.sbEnd.ToString)
        sbExisting.AppendLine(Report.sbCol.ToString)
    Case tFile.EndsWith("FileB.doc")
        'Slave
        sbExisting.AppendLine(Report.sbStart.ToString)
        sbExisting.AppendLine(Report.sbItems.ToString)
        sbExisting.AppendLine(Report.sbHeaders.ToString)
        sbExisting.AppendLine(Report.sbCol.ToString)
        sbExisting.AppendLine(Report.sbEnd.ToString)
End Select
```

Comment: I think just `Select Case True` would do it, instead of `Select Case tFile.EndsWith(tFile)` (which will always be true anyway)

Comment: It actually works as expected with the code above; Properly distinguishing against either case.

Comment: Just because something works as expected does not mean it's efficient or simple.

Comment: I couldn't agree more. I was simply clarifying that the code itself works correctly. The intent of my post is to find an eloquent solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.EndsWith()` returns true or false. That's all you have.

If you do want to use `Select` with that, then the idiomatic way is

```
Select Case True
    Case tFile.EndsWith("MSMaster.tmp")
        ...
    Case tFile.EndsWith("MSSlave.tmp")
        ...
End Select
```

Having multiple choices on the same line would be of not much difference:

```
Select Case True
    Case tFile.EndsWith("example 1"), tFile.EndsWith("example 2")
        ...
    Case tFile.EndsWith("example 3"), tFile.EndsWith("example 4")
        ...
End Select
```

If you already have a list of choices in an array/list/collection, you can also use

```
Dim choices1 = New String() {"example 1", "example 2"}
Dim choices2 = New String() {"example 3", "example 4"}

Select Case True
    Case choices1.Any(Function(s) tFile.EndsWith(s))
        ...
    Case choices2.Any(Function(s) tFile.EndsWith(s))
        ...
End Select
```

Or do the same inline if you prefer:

```
Select Case True
    Case (New String() {"example 1", "example 2"}).Any(Function(s) tFile.EndsWith(s))
        ...
    Case (New String() {"example 3", "example 4"}).Any(Function(s) tFile.EndsWith(s))
        ...
End Select
```

Comment: Your first post was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between the 2 cases is the appending of the `sbSubreport` item.  That is the only item which needs a special check and can be done like the following

```
Dim master = tFile.EndsWith("MSMaster.tmp")
Dim slave = tFile.EndsWith("MSSlave.tmp")
If master OrElse slave Then
    sbExisting.AppendLine(Report.sbStart.ToString)
    sbExisting.AppendLine(Report.sbHeaders.ToString)
    sbExisting.AppendLine(Report.sbItems.ToString)
    If master Then
        sbExisting.AppendLine(Report.sbSubreport.ToString)
    End If
    sbExisting.AppendLine(Report.sbEnd.ToString)
    sbExisting.AppendLine(Report.sbCol.ToString)
End If
```

Comment: The code is only a prototype to the actual project. This solution would only work for the specific circumstance. Interesting all the same.